# Add a key/value to datagridview combobox after binding

Tags: c#, vb.net, datagridview, combobox

I am having trouble handling errors regarding DataGridView ComboBoxes.

Ideally, if, when loading my DataGridView Combobox column and a corresponding key is not found, I would like to display the key along with an error message using .ErrorText AND NOT have said key appear as an option in the Combobox.

This problem is spawning from the fact that there are different "categories" for each object, and each category has a different set of values available for the DataGridView Combobox column.  When the user changes the category an object belongs to, the options selected in my DataGridView Combobox may or may not be part of that category.  The entire column will have the same options available to it.  Validation happens when saving, so having "invalid" entries in the grid is not a problem, but I would like to guide the user towards only valid options.

At the moment I am populating my Combobox column like:

```
colTest.Populate("myTable", "ID", "Value", "WHERE categoryID = 1")

<Extension>
Public Sub Populate(ByRef cbo As DatagridviewComboboxColumn, table As String, key As String, value As String, Optional where As String = "")
    Dim mySQLAccess As CustomSQLAccess 'Using Dll to interact with SQL'
    Dim myTmpTable As DataTable
    Dim comboBox = New Dictionary(Of Integer, String)

    Try
        myTmpTable = mySQLAccess.ExecuteSelectQuery("SELECT " + key + ", " + value + " FROM " + table + " " + where)

        For Each row As DataRow In myTmpTable.Rows
            comboBox.Add(row.Item(0), row.Item(1))
        Next

        If comboBox IsNot Nothing Then
            cbo.DataSource = New BindingSource(comboBox, Nothing)
            cbo.DisplayMember = "Value"
            cbo.ValueMember = "Key"
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        'Error handling'
    End Try
End Sub
```

I would like to set the error message and add "Invalid" entries on the .DataError event but am unsure how to code it.

```
Private Sub myGrid_DataError(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles myGrid.DataError

    Dim view2 = CType(sender, DataGridView)
    view2.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "an error"
    view2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex).ErrorText = "an error"

End Sub
```

If it is not possible to display the key without having it as an option in the Combobox, would it be possible to add the (key, "key") to the Combobox?